# Android Studio Blurry Second Icon on Plank

Tags: release-freya

I am having an issue with keeping the Android Studio app on my dock. It's the same with google-chrome but I haven't found any easy way to get rid of it. Whenever I open up the application, a blurry second icon pops up, just like the google-chrome icon issue. If anybody could help me, that would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: It worked! Thank you for that simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have it's .desktop file installed in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications`? If you do, add `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio` to it, it should work then.